# Excel macro loops for taking values from a range of cells and filenaming

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have an Excel macro (own recorded), which does following:
in the column A (A1-A90) are placed different formulas. Formula calculation is set to manual.
The macro

- copies formula from A1
- creates new file
- pastes formula into A1 of newly created file
- calculates the formel
- saves the file

The macro code is:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
   Windows("macrotest.xlsx").Activate
   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Calculate
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
       "Z:\Mappe1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
       CreateBackup:=False

  Windows("macrotest.xlsx").Activate    
    Range("A2").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Calculate
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
       "Z:\Mappe2.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
       CreateBackup:=False

   Windows("macrotest.xlsx").Activate
   Range("A3").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Calculate
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
       "Z:\Mappe3.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
       CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

I have more then 100 formulas, so it would be nice to have two loops in the macro instead of paste 100 code snippets into macro code:

- one loop would take formulas from the range A1-A90 one by one to paste into created files
- second loop would give forthcoming file names on saving files (not important, which names - 1.csv to 100.csv is fully enough).

Please point me to right loops.Thanks.

**Upd**:
Based on advice from Tim Edwards i build up this macro:

```
Sub MyMacro()
  Dim i As Integer, myname As String
    myname = ThisWorkbook.Name
    For i = 1 To 90
Windows(myname).Activate
Range("A" & i).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Calculate
ActiveSheet.Calculate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "Z:\file" & i & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
    CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True 
  Next i
 End Sub
```

But the problem on it is, that the **formulas in saved files aren't calculated** - i get only the pasted formulas into a1.

Does somebody see the cause, why formulas aren't calculated before saving? I tried all kinds of formula calculation setting - automatic, manual, manual on saving.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim i as integer
For i = 1 to 100

   Windows("macrotest.xlsx").Activate
   Range("A" & i).Copy
   Workbooks.Add
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Calculate
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "Z:\Mappe" & i & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make one loop going from 1 to 90.

```
    For i = 1 To 90


    Next i
```

In each iteration:

- Get the formula from Cells(i, 1).
- Paste into a new workbook and calculate.
- Save the workbook as "directory.." + i +".csv".